# Exponentially Weighted Covariance Matrix in Python

Tags: python, pandas, covariance, exponential

I have weekly return data in ascending order. Suppose I want to calculate exponentially weighted moving covariance matrix, with suppose half life of 5 years or 260 weeks. I am trying to follow pandas.DataFrame.ewm, but not really clear about how to implement this in my case. Given I can't mention halflife, as "Only applicable to mean() and halflife value will not apply to the other functions."

Using alpha = 1-exp(ln(0.5)/HalfLife) = 2/(span + 1), I used span = 750.

ret is my return data frame with DatetimeIndex.
`ret.shape` is `(895, 11)`

I tried `SigmaExpW = ret.ewm(span = 750).cov()`, but result is not what I expected. `SigmaExpW.shape` is `(9845, 11)`.

For context -

```
ret.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 895 entries, 2003-06-04 to 2020-07-22
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   GE           895 non-null    float64
 1   IGM          895 non-null    float64
 2   USLC         895 non-null    float64
 3   USSC         895 non-null    float64
 4   ExUS         895 non-null    float64
 5   ExUSHedged   895 non-null    float64
 6   EM           895 non-null    float64
 7   Commodities  895 non-null    float64
 8   HYM          895 non-null    float64
 9   Government   895 non-null    float64
 10  Cash         895 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(11)
```

I am clearly making some elementary mistake. Would appreciate help.

Comment: You can construct the EWM by its half life: `ret.ewm(halflife=260).cov()`. This will calculate the alpha accordingly for you

Comment: Tried that. Same result. ```SigmaExpW.shape``` is ```(9845, 11)```

Answer (score 0):

It creates `11*11` matrix everyday. `895*11 = 9845`